# I think my program is giving an inaccurate result for Riemann Sums

Tags: java

this is my first post here!

So, as an extra credit project for my Calculus course, the professor offered us an opportunity to write a simple program that calculates the area under a user specified curve. I realize this isn't the best way to implement this, but he say's that's fine, but I think this is giving me the wrong answer. Could anyone help?

```
import java.util.*;

public class RiemannSum2 {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        System.out.println("This is a Riemann Sum Calculator. This calculator accepts polynomials in the form of a(x)^ex + b(x)^ex2 + c, where c is a constant.");

        System.out.print("Enter the first coeffecient of the polynomial: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int firstCoe = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the exponent of the first term: ");
        int firstExp = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second coeffecient of the polynomial: ");
        int secondCoe = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the exponent of the second term: ");
        int secondExp = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the third term of the polynomial: ");
        int thirdTerm = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the x value that you want to start the Riemann Sum: ");
        int startX = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the x value to stop the Riemann Sum: ");
        int endX = sc.nextInt();


        String poly = (firstCoe+"x^"+firstExp+"+"+secondCoe+"x^"+secondExp+"+"+thirdTerm);

        System.out.println("Your polynomial is: "+poly);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rectangles you want: ");
        int rectangles = sc.nextInt();

        double numerator = (endX-startX);
        double rectanglesD = (double)rectangles;

        double constantWidth = numerator/rectanglesD;

        System.out.println("This is the constant width: " + constantWidth);
        double totalSum = 0;
        //System.out.println(totalSum);
        for(int i = 0; i < rectangles ; i++) {

            totalSum = totalSum+((Math.pow((firstCoe * (i/constantWidth)), firstExp)) + (Math.pow((secondCoe * (i/constantWidth)), secondExp))+thirdTerm);

        }

        totalSum = totalSum*constantWidth;
        System.out.println("The Riemann Sum of your polynomial is roughly equivalent to: "+ totalSum);

    }
}
```

Comment: Beyond a mere *belief* that it may be producing inaccurate results, a *tangible* example of said results (and the inputs that resulted in the aforementioned results) would be helpful. Is there some reason you believe the results are inaccurate? And is your question how to get more accurate results?

Comment: I don't know Riemann Sums but the problem it certainly is in loop ' for ' where you calculate a ' totalSum '... 
My suggest is to reproduce the steps of the algorithm to add up ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `(i/constantWidth)` to calculate the argument of your function (`x`). However, it should be

```
double x = startX + i * constantWidth;
```

Furthermore, your coefficients should be outside of the `pow` function. Otherwise, they will get exponentiated too. Removing some of the superfluous parentheses makes the formula a lot easier to read. Like this:

```
double x = startX + i * constantWidth;
totalSum = totalSum
               + firstCoe * Math.pow(x, firstExp)
               + secondCoe * Math.pow(x, secondExp)
               + thirdTerm;
```

Unrelated to the code: Since you have a simple polynomial, you can calculate the antiderivative analytically and simply evaluate that function instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for  your help! You were right, the parenthesis were a bit excessive. Thank You!